# cordova ios video - saveToPhotoAlbum - not working

Tags: cordova-3

saveToPhotoAlbum: true - this flag should make the video saved to PhotoAlbum.

I'm using cordova 3.3 and it doesn't work.

It does work for image, it also does work for android.

Any idea how to overcome this?

Comment: please put some of your work, i.e. code here

Comment: Its just a code from the docs, with the option set to true…

Answer (score 0):

Using cordova 3.5-dev, after installing the capture plugin, in CDVCaptrure.m, line 293 (function processVideo) it says:

```
/* don't need, it should automatically get saved
 NSLog(@"can save %@: %d ?", moviePath, UIVideoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum(moviePath));
if (&UIVideoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum != NULL && UIVideoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum(moviePath) == YES) {
    NSLog(@"try to save movie");
    UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(moviePath, nil, nil, nil);
    NSLog(@"finished saving movie");
}*/
```

change it to:

```
NSLog(@"can save %@: %d ?", moviePath, UIVideoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum(moviePath));
if (&UIVideoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum != NULL && UIVideoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum(moviePath) == YES) {
    NSLog(@"try to save movie");
    UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(moviePath, nil, nil, nil);
    NSLog(@"finished saving movie");
}
```